# Left Join com coalesce

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho as seguintes tabelas `setores(idsetor,sigla,ativo)` e outra com os servicos executados chamada de `ordem_servico(id,numero,idsetor,)`. Quero contar quantos servicos determinado setor cancelou e quando não retorne 0.

Estou tentando assim: Mas não funcionou, se tirar o coalesce funciona mas ele conta o null e retorna 1

```
SELECT a.sigla, COALESCE(COUNT(*) as numero,0) FROM setores a left join ordem_servico b on b.idsetor = a.idsetor and b.ano = '2017' and b.status = 'Cancelada'  WHERE a.ativo = 'Sim' group by a.sigla
```

Answer (score 2):

Consegui:

SELECT a.sigla, COALESCE(COUNT(numero),0) as numero FROM setores a left join ordem_servico b on b.idsetor = a.idsetor and b.ano = '2017' and b.status = 'Cancelada'  WHERE a.ativo = 'Sim' group by a.sigla